# Problemas al importar un archivo xml a un base de datos MySQL utilizando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Buen día, tengo el siguiente problema, espero me puedan ayudar. Quiero importar un archivo XML a una base de datos de MySQL utilizando el siguiente código.
Mi archivo XML, es el siguiente:

```
<xml>
   <clubnet>01/12/2017</clubnet>
      <escuelas>
          <escuela>
               <escuela>01</escuela>
               <Domicilio>FAJARDO# 163</Domicilio>
               <ciudad>ZAMORA</ciudad>
               <estado>MICHOACAN</estado>
               <encargado>PROF. JUANPEREZ</encargado>
               <telefono>3511231222</telefono>
               <Nombre>TAEKWONDO</Nombre>
               <Registro>.</Registro>
               <Folio>0</Folio>
               <puesto>PROFESOR ESCUELA</puesto>
               <referencia>E.C</referencia>
               <status>0</status>
               <escuelapadre>.</escuelapadre>
       </escuela>
   </escuelas>
</xml>
```

Y EL CÓDIGO PHP ES EL SIGUIENTE:

```
<?php 

$xml_file = 'escuelas_2.xml';

if (file_exists($xml_file)) {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
  echo "ARCHIVO XML CARGADO EXITOSAMENTE <br><br>";
} 
else {
  exit('Error al intentar abrir el fichero '.$xml_file);
}

require 'conexion.php';

$count=0; 

foreach ($xml->escuelas as $escuela) {

      $qry = "INSERT INTO escuelas (escuela, Domicilio, ciudad, estado, encargado,telefono,Nombre , Registro, Folio,puesto, referencia,status,escuelapadre)
          VALUES ('$escuela->escuela','$escuela->Domicilio','$escuela->ciudad','$escuela->estado','$escuela->encargado','$escuela->telefono','$escuela->Nombre','$escuela->Registro','$escuela->Folio','$escuela->puesto','$escuela->referencia','$escuela->status','$escuela->escuelapadre')";

      $resultado=mysqli_query($link,$qry) or die(mysqli_error());
      if($resultado)
        echo "INSERCIÓN REALIZADA CON EXITO";
      else
        echo "INSERCIÓN NO REALIZADA";


      $count++;
}//foreach

echo "
"; echo "-------------------------------------------
"; echo "Total de escuelas importadas: $count properties
"; echo "-------------------------------------------
";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta hacerlo así:

1. Puedes emplear [`$xml->escuelas->children()`](http://php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.children.php) para obtener el arreglo de escuelas.
2. Y para acceder a las propiedades de cada `$escuela`, puedes [castear el objeto a arreglo](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) (`eg: $escuela = (array) $escuela;`)

Ejemplo:

```
<?php 

$xml_file = 'escuelas_2.xml';

if (file_exists($xml_file)) {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
  echo "ARCHIVO XML CARGADO EXITOSAMENTE <br><br>";
} 
else {
  exit('Error al intentar abrir el fichero '.$xml_file);
}

require 'conexion.php';

$count=0; 

foreach ($xml->escuelas->children() as $escuela) {

      $escuela = (array) $escuela;

      $qry = "INSERT INTO escuelas (escuela, Domicilio, ciudad, estado,
      encargado,telefono,Nombre , Registro, Folio,puesto, referencia,status,escuelapadre)
      VALUES
      ('$escuela[escuela]','$escuela[Domicilio]','$escuela[ciudad]','$escuela[estado]',
      '$escuela[encargado]','$escuela[telefono]','$escuela[Nombre]','$escuela[Registro]',
      '$escuela[Folio]','$escuela[puesto]','$escuela[referencia]','$escuela[status]',
      '$escuela[escuelapadre]')";

      $resultado=mysqli_query($link,$qry) or die(mysqli_error());
      if($resultado)
        echo "INSERCIÓN REALIZADA CON EXITO";
      else
        echo "INSERCIÓN NO REALIZADA";


      $count++;
}//foreach

echo "
"; echo "-------------------------------------------
"; echo "Total de escuelas importadas: $count properties
"; echo "-------------------------------------------
";

?>
```

Comment: Oye me duplica los registros, ya me los carga pero los agrega dos veces a la base de datos. Que podrá ser?? Gracias de antemano, saludos

Comment: @Condor_G, el `foreach` itera el arreglo devuelto por `children()`, por lo que no deberían cargarse dos veces. Cada vez que ejecutas el código ¿estas vaciando la tabla? ¿validas de alguna forma que no acepte duplicados?

Comment: Hola  Marcos, ya está funcionando a la perfección el código, ando medio dormido y tenía yo un error medio tonto, pero ya lo corregí, tu código funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias por el apoyo!!! Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que mejor trabajes los xml con una libreria pro ejemplo esta https://github.com/prewk/xml-string-streamer.

Ejemplo

```html
use Prewk\XmlStringStreamer;
use Prewk\XmlStringStreamer\Stream;
use Prewk\XmlStringStreamer\Parser;

// Prepare our stream to be read with a 1kb buffer
$stream = new Stream\File("gigantic.xml", 1024);

// Construct the default parser (StringWalker)
$parser = new Parser\StringWalker();

// Create the streamer
$streamer = new XmlStringStreamer($parser, $stream);

// Iterate through the `<customer>` nodes
while ($node = $streamer->getNode()) {
    // $node will be a string like this: "<customer><firstName>Jane</firstName><lastName>Doe</lastName></customer>"
    $simpleXmlNode = simplexml_load_string($node);
    echo (string)$simpleXmlNode->firstName;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, saludos.